# Issue while handle user typing notification using notificatincenter

Tags: ios, swift, notificationcenter

I am creating an chat application using socket.io, every things going perfect but when I am handling user typing notification I am getting error like below

**Error:**

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[SocketChat.ChatViewController
>   handleUserTypingNotification:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0x7f817653d710

and now I will show you my code for better expiation

**Code:**

```
private func listenForOtherMessages() {
    socket.on("userTypingUpdate") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userTypingNotification"), object: dataArray[0] as? [String: AnyObject])}
}
```

Here I am managing method which I am getting from index.js file and from another viewcontroller. I manage with notification center like bellow

```
let notificationCenter4 = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter4.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("handleUserTypingNotification")), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userTypingNotification"), object: nil)
```

I don't understand why this error is coming and what does it exactly mean. Can any one please help me?

```
import UIKit

class ChatViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let notificationCenter4 = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter4.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleUserTypingNotification)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userTypingNotification"), object: nil)
    }

    func handleKeyboardDidShowNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                conBottomEditor.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector signature is wrong. It should look like this.

```
let notificationCenter4 = NotificationCenter.default
notificationCenter4.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShowNotification(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userTypingNotification"), object: nil)
```

In your code you are creating a *new* instance, while you probably have a selector already. Something like this.

```
@objc func handleKeyboardDidShowNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
    if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
        if let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
            conBottomEditor.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
            view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cannot invoke 'addObserver' with an argument list of type '(ChatViewController, selector: Selector) .  Still i am getting this type of error

Comment: @Vishal Where is your selector located? please edit the question and add the code for the full class showing your selector.

Comment: @Vishal you have added the class from where the notifications are posted. You need to show the class where your notifications are observed. The class which contains the line in my answer.

Comment: please check now its proper or not?

Comment: @Vishal you do not seem to have your selector declared anywhere. Check my answer i have shown how you need to declare your selector.

Comment: Please check question which i have updated u mean to say same or not

Comment: Yes now i am not getting error but still i am not getting notification not able to understand where i am doing wrong

Comment: @Vishal is your `handleKeyboardDidShowNotification` being executed?

Comment: @Vishal is your notification being posted? Also the question is about an exception, which seems to have been solved. Please post another question outlining your new problem.

Comment: i have one more question this will work only on device or we can able to check in simulator?

Comment: Ok wait i am putting new question Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179676/discussion-between-vishal-and-rakesha-shastri).