# Issue while usertyping notification not handled

Tags: ios, swift, socket.io, nsnotificationcenter

I am creating chat app with socket.io but I am not able to handle usertyping notification I don't know where I am doing wrong I show my code

**Code:**

from here I am posting my notification

```
func listenForOtherMessages() {
  socket.on("userTypingUpdate") { (dataArray, socketAck) -> Void in
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userTypingNotification"), object: dataArray[0] as? [String: AnyObject])
        }
    }
```

from here I am handing my notification

```
  @objc func handleKeyboardDidShowNotification(notification: NSNotification) {
        if let userInfo = notification.userInfo {
            if let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue {
                conBottomEditor.constant = keyboardFrame.size.height
                view.layoutIfNeeded()
            }
        }
    }
```

and last here I am putting my selector but my notification posted successfully but still i did now receive

```
 let notificationCenter4 = NotificationCenter.default
        notificationCenter4.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(handleKeyboardDidShowNotification(notification:)), name:NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "userTypingNotification"), object: nil)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Issue while handle user typing notification using notificatincenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52233830/issue-while-handle-user-typing-notification-using-notificatincenter)

Comment: No that also my question but that not solve for me

Comment: But you accept that answer.

Comment: Yes because i have other problem at that time like i am getting crash and now thats solved but still i am not getting notification

Comment: so instead of posting another question you need to ask in that question with edit.

Comment: @Vishal is your notification being posted? Also the question is about an exception, which seems to have been solved. Please post another question outlining your new problem.   i am getting suggestion to post new que. so i post it

Comment: why you think this **if let keyboardFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue** has a value despite it's not a subscribe to keyboard shown notification ??